# Half-wave plate (HWP) Hadamard gate implementation

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, hadamard

The transformation of a qubit encoded in the polarization state from $|H\rangle$ to the state $|+\rangle$ is theoretically achievable with an HWP@π/8. However, I rarely see this solution in experimental articles. Why is that?

Comment: Hi, welcome to QCSE.  I'd recommend you edit the posting to (1) spell out "half-wave plate" at least in the title of the question; (2) and provide links to at least one reference that you  think should refer to a HWP but uses another technique that surprises you?

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your comment